# Text plot with Python

Tags: python-3.x, plot

Is there any way to plot some text in desired position with python?

Example:

```
plot_text(x=5, y=3, text='I am a boy')
```

(x,y) is the coordinate where text'll start it's plot.

Comment: Position on what, exactly?

Comment: position or the coordinate. @Josh Lee

Answer (score 0):

The `axes` object in `matplotlib.pyplot` offers a simple method, `text()` for plotting text.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(5, 3, "I am a boy")
ax.set_xlim([0,7]) # Expand the plot limits to include the text. 
ax.set_ylim([0,7])
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

However, the method `annotate()` provides additional features for ease in annotating data.